# Entity Framework Ambient Transactions

Tags: c#

I have read that when a `DbContext.SaveChanges()` runs all the operations are automatically wrapped in a transaction for you behind the scenes. That is, if any of the operations inside during `SaveChanges()` fail, everything is rolled back maintaining consistent state.

However, one term I've come across several times is that the changes can run as part of an ambient transaction. What exactly does that mean?

My specific concern is: I have a multithreaded application, in which I have one context per operation. None of my DbContext objects are shared across different threads. Am I guaranteed that the operations of each `DbContext.SaveChanges()` will run in separate transactions?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

In your case, yes, you are guaranteed that each DbContext.SaveChanges() will run in separate transactions.

The term "ambient" transaction refers to a transaction that was started higher-up in the call stack.  So that this is a per-thread concept.  See [Transaction.Current](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.transactions.transaction.current%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) and [TransactionScope](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.transactions.transaction.current%28v=vs.110%29.aspx).  It is a feature that allows you do to something like this:

```
using (TransactionScope scope123 = new TransactionScope())
    {
        using (SqlConnection connection1 = new SqlConnection(connectString1))
        {
            // Do some work
            using (SqlConnection connection2 = new SqlConnection(connectString2))
            {
                // Do some more work
            }
        }
```

Both of the above connections automatically use the "ambient" transaction "scope123."  It sounds like the entity framework now knows how to do this.  But the TransactionScope won't cross threads, so you are okay.  And it doesn't sound like you are explicitly creating transaction scopes anyway.

Comment: This is what I was hoping for, just needed confirmation. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

Based on this: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/data/dn456843.aspx

By default, SaveChanges will open a new transaction, and dispose of it once complete.  In EF 6, functionality was added such that you can override this behavior.  So long as you don't go out of your way to reuse transactions - you should be okay.

Comment: "Starting with EF6 Database.ExecuteSqlCommand() by default will wrap the command in a transaction if one was not already present": this is my concern. What if a transaction was started by a DbContext on a separate thread. Will this thread see it?

Comment: Are your DbContexts on separate threads sharing the same database connection?  If not, then one context would never be aware of a transaction started by another.  No?